# Symfony2 - Change the layout of the entity checkboxes

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I'm trying to learn Symfony2.

I created an Entity (Facility) and I give it this presentaion in the database:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID  |  Parent_ID  |  Label  |  created_at  |  updated_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |    NULL     |  Fi P   |  3/6/2015    |  3/6/2015
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  2   |    NULL     |  Sec P  |  3/6/2015    |  3/6/2015
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  3   |      1      |  Ch 1   |  3/6/2015    |  3/6/2015
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  4   |      2      |  Ch 2   |  3/6/2015    |  3/6/2015
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this Entity is in Many-To-Many relationship with "Apartement".

In the ApartementType form there is :

```
->add('facilities','entity', array(
     'class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Facility',
     'multiple' => true ,
     'expanded' => true,
     'required' => false
))
```

And it generate checkboxes, until here everything is fine.

I wanted to change the display of the checkboxes to display every parent inside a 'Parent Name' (as a title), and it's children as checkboxes.

like:

```
Parent Name #1
+checkbox1  +checkbox2  +checkbox3  +checkbox4

Parent Name #2
+checkbox1  +checkbox2  +checkbox3  +checkbox4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extends the block who renders the checkbox field.

This block is declared in this file `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`.

All you have to do now is ( in your template ):

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {%- for child in form %}
        {# INSERT HERE PARENT NAME #}
        PARENTNAME
        {{- form_widget(child) -}}
        {{- form_label(child) -}}
    {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}
```

Now you can change the way forms are rendered. It will output `PARENTNAME` Before each checkbox row

But now, what if you want to add a variable instead of a fixed string?

You have to add it to your field ( in your FormType):

```
protected $parentName;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->parentName = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['parentname'] = $this->parentName;
}
```

Last but not least, in your template, the extended render for the filed is now:

```
{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {%- for child in form %}
        {{ form.vars.parentName[loop.index] }}
        {{- form_widget(child) -}}
        {{- form_label(child) -}}
    {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}
```

PS: This is the global scheme, I'm not sure this is this particular field you want to extend, but now you can try the one you need by looking in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`.

Comment: hey **Med** thank you for your response, the result shows me only the fields and not the data.

Comment: Which symfony version do you use, and are you using bootstrap theme ?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.6 and I'm not using bootstrap.